# (Flutter/Dart) How to kill process after Process.start

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this Future function:

```
Future<Process> executeCommand(List<String> args) async {
  var process = await Process.start('java', args, workingDirectory: folder);
  return process;
}

process = await ref.read(searchControllerProvider).executeCommand(cmd);
await stdout.addStream(process.stdout);
```

It's supposed to execute a command to run a jar file. How do I add a button to kill the process before it ends? Neither `Process.killPid(process.pid)` nor `process.kill()` is working. `killPid` returns `true` the first time I click the button, but it's still running.

Comment: According the the documentation for Process.start it does not use the search path to locate the executable; you should use an absolute path. If I am right, this means that you may be getting something back on the stderr stream and the documentation says: "If the user does not read all data on the [stdout and stderr] streams the underlying system resources will not be released since there is still pending data". Try it and if I am right I will put this in as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was more of a jar problem and not a Dart/Flutter one.
The `pid` that Dart gives with `process.pid` is not the correct one which is used by the jar file.

I ended up running Java's `jps` command and looping through the output to search for the correct pid.

```
String javaBinPath = '${Platform.environment['JAVA_HOME']}\\bin';
var jps = Process.runSync('jps', [], workingDirectory: javaBinPath, runInShell: true);
for (var line in LineSplitter.split(jps.stdout)) {
  List<String> parts = line.split(' ');
  int pid = int.parse(parts[0]);
  String name = parts[1];
  if (name == 'x.jar') {
    Process.killPid(pid);
    break;
  }
}
```

It's an ugly solution, but it works.